# glActiveTexture undeclared identifier 'GL_TEXTURE0'

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, ios8

In my iOS 8 testing, everything seems to be working fine but now I'm getting issues with my OpenGLES framework where the gl header file exists, but for some reason it says that the GL_TEXTURE0 definition (along with various other definitions) cannot be found.

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
```

Exact error:

```
Implicit declaration of function glActiveTexture is invalid in C99.

Use of undeclared identifier 'GL_TEXTURE0'
```

This could be because I may be importing the framework incorrectly, but this is how I've been using it and it works fine in iOS 7 and below.

```
#import <OpenGLES/EAGL.h>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the reasoning is, but I changed my import statements as follows:

```
#import <OpenGLES/ES2/gl.h>
#import <OpenGLES/ES2/glext.h>
```

This seems to resolve the issue.

Comment: Well, you need to import the OpenGL headers to get the definitions of OpenGL functions. That shouldn't be a big surprise. I believe some other header may have indirectly pulled in the OpenGL headers in older versions of the SDK, and this changed in iOS 8. But you were always supposed to have these imports when using OpenGL. It's just that you happened to get away with missing them before.